# SFCC: Is there a way to automatically remove custom attribute definitions

Tags: salesforce-commerce-cloud

We have a pretty old project where we have a lot of custom attribute definitions but do not trust our `sites/site_template/meta/system-objecttype-extensions.xml` to be complete.

Does anybody know of a way to remove a defined set of custom attribute definitions automatically? We can identify quite a lot that are definitely not used anymore but I'm missing the DELETE import functionality available for other types of data in SFCC.

Tx a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What to do, so I wrote my own parser / analyser / merger: https://github.com/Andreas-Schoenefeldt/SFCCAnalyser#combine-and-analyse-system-objecttype-extension-xml-files

It can be used like this:

1. put all xml files you would like to merge into one in `./data/meta-xmls/`
2. run `node combine-xml.js`
3. the resulting merged and cleaned xml file will be in `./data/meta-xmls/combined.xml`

The resulting file will contain all custom attribute definitions accross the systems, so it can then safely imported checking the **Delete existing attribute definitions and attribute groups not contained in the import file, including attribute definitions marked as "externally-defined".**